# Sagemaker environment variable with .env

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

**[Background]**

I am used to use `xx.py` and defining a `.env` file in python project in Pycharm, and by doing

```
import os
os.environ['abc']
```

I will get the 'abc' variable defined in `.env` file.

**[Question]**

Now I need to work with sagemake studio, what is the **best practice** to manage env var with sagemake?

I tried to create a `.env` file, but got a rename error. Does it mean using `.env` is not a good try in sagemaker?

```
Rename Error
Cannot rename file or directory '/xx/untitled.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Steps followed:

1. Create a text file. E.g. EnvVars.txt
2. Added two lines:

- ENTRY1=VALUE1
- FOO=BAR

3. In the SageMaker studio notebook cell added the following:

- from dotenv import load_dotenv
- load_dotenv("EnvVars.txt")

PS: Make sure you do pip install python-dotenv beforehand via terminal or another notebook cell.

4. print(os.getenv('ENTRY1')) # This gives VALUE1